# How to use Compile with list as argument

Tags: compile

I want to use Compile for a function that takes 5 arguments (the function that is being compiled is not actually this one, but I am just using an example):

```
    isingfunc = 
 Compile[{{J1, _Real, 1}, {H, _Real, 1}, {TB, _Real, 1}, {Th, _Real, 
    1}, {Tc, _Real, 1}},J1 + H + TB + TH + Tc]
```

And the arguments that I would want to use would came from a random gererated list in the form of:

```
    Table[{J = RandomInteger[{-1, -10}], 
  h = RandomInteger[{2, 15}] + 1/RandomInteger[{1, 10}], 
  Tb1 = RandomInteger[{100, 400}]/10, 
  TH1 = RandomInteger[{1, Floor[Tb1]}]/RandomInteger[{1, 10}], 
  tc1 = RandomInteger[{1, Floor[TH1]}]/RandomInteger[{1, 10}]}, {k, 1,
   10}]
```

However, when I use one of the lists generated in the compiled function (`isingfunc[{-9, 8.5, 33.8, 4.33, 0.12}]`, for instance), I am not able to correctly use the arguments in the compiled function. It gives erros like: `Argument -9 at position 1 should be a rank 1 tensor of machine-size real numbers`.

Any ideas of what I am doing wrong, and how to use a list as the argument of `Compile`?

Comment: You are declaring each of your arguments to be rank 1 tensors of reals, i.e. a list of reals. Declare them as `Compile[{{J1, _Real}, ...}, ...]` instead. Your function call should also be `isingfunc[-9, 8.5, 33.8, 4.33, 0.12]`, i.e. without enclosing your arguments in braces. If your function is fed a list, you can use `isingfun @@ yourList`. Or alternatively you can declare a single list as input and use the solution proposed in the answer below.

Comment: The "isingfun @@ yourList" works. Thanks @MarcoB

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
isingfunc = Compile[{{x, _Real, 1}}, Total[x], RuntimeAttributes -> {Listable}]
```

Test:

```
isingfunc[{-9, 8.5, 33.8, 4.33, 0.12}]
(*37.75*)
```